# Access the next word/string

Tags: c, string, pointers, file-handling

I have a simple C-based code to read a file. Read the input line by line. Tokenize the line and prints the current token. My problem is, I want to print the next token if some conditions are satisfied. Do you have any idea how to do it. I really need your help for this project. Thank you 
Here is the code:

```
main(){

FILE *input;
FILE *output;
//char filename[100];

const char *filename = "sample1.txt";
input=fopen(filename,"r");
output=fopen("test.st","w");
char word[1000];
char *token;
int num =0;
char var[100];

fprintf(output,"LEXEME, TOKEN");
while( fgets(word, 1000, input) != NULL ){ //reads a line

token = strtok(word, " \t\n" ); // tokenize the line    
while(token!=NULL){ // while line is not equal to null
    fprintf(output,"\n");
    if (strcmp(token,"SIOL")==0)
        fprintf(output,"SIOL, SIOL", token);
    else if (strcmp(token,"DEFINE")==0)
        fprintf(output,"DEFINE, DEFINE", token);
    else if (strcmp(token,"INTEGER")==0){
        fprintf(output,"INTEGER, INTEGER");
        strcpy(var,token+1);
        fprintf(output,"\n%s,Ident",var);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }       
    token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n" ); //tokenize the word     
}}fclose(output);return 0;}
```

Comment: have you tried `strtok`?

Comment: `strtok` is a good option, but if I understand you correctly, that you want to print or not print the next based on  some condition with the current, then if you are parsing the line in a serial manner, why not just skip to the following space or newline in the 'no print' case. You will need to post more details to get more detailed help. Not knowing what you are currently doing drastically limits the help you can get.

Comment: yes, that's what i used to tokenized the line. I could print the current token. What i need is to print the next or upcoming token if some condition is satisfied. For instance the string is, "The quick brown fox"
Current token is 'The'. If (strcmp("The", "The")==0) printf ("quick").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. I'm not sure I completely understand what you need, but if you have the string:

```
"The quick brown fox";
```

And, you want to tokenize the string, printing the *next* word, only if a condition concerning the *current* word is met, then you need to adjust your thinking just a bit. In your example, you want to print the *next* word `"quick"`, only if the *current* word is `"The"`.

The adjustment in thinking is how you look at the test. Instead of thinking about printing the *next* word if the *current* matches some condition, you need to save the *last* word, and only print the *current* if the *last* word matches some condition -- `"The"` in your example.

To handle that situation, you can make use of a statically declared character array of at least `47` characters (the longest word in Merriam-Websters Unabridged Dictionary is 46-character). I'll use `48` in the example below. You may be tempted to just save a pointer to the last word, but when using `strtok` there is no guarantee that the memory address returned by the previous iteration is preserved -- so make a copy of the word.

Putting the pieces together, you could do something like the following. It saves the prior token in `last` and then compares the current word to the last and prints the current word if `last == "The"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXW 48

int main (void) {

    char str[] = "The quick brown fox";
    char last[MAXW] = {0};
    char *p;

    for (p = strtok (str, " "); p; p = strtok (NULL, " ")) 
    {
        if (*last && strcmp (last, "The") == 0)
            printf (" '%s'\n", p);
        strncpy (last, p, MAXW);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_chk_last
 'quick'
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

---

**Test Explanation**

As written in the comment `*last` is simply shorthand for `last[0]`. So the first part of the test, `*last` is just testing `if ((last[0] != 0) && ..`. Since last was initially declared and initialized:

```
char last[MAXW] = {0};
```

All chars in `last` are `0` for the first pass through the loop. By including the check `last[0] != 0`, that just causes the `printf` to be skipped the first time the `for` loop executes. The longhand for the test would look like:

```
    if ((last[0] != 0) && strcmp (last, "The") == 0)
        printf (" '%s'\n", p);
```

Which in *pseudo code* just says:

```
    if (NOT first iteration && last == "The")
        printf (" '%s'\n", p);
```

Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I got your point Mr.@david. I'll try to use it and I will let you know if it works. Thank you so much for the response. You got my question correctly by the way.

Comment: if (*last && strcmp (last, "The") == 0)

I wonder what is the meaning of *last in this statement

Comment: Sorry, that is just shorthand for `last[0]`. It is just a check that the first char in the string is not `'\0'`. (which is numeric `0` -- otherwise know as the `null-terminating` character) Think of it this way. in pointer notation `array[0]` is `*(array + 0)`, the `+ 0` doesn't do anything, so `*array` is just a shortcut for `array[0]` and the test in full is `((array[0] != '\0') && ..`. All of which means it is just skipping the first iteration -- because `*array` is NULL then by initialization. (e.g. `char last[MAXW] = {0};`) Hope that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to achieve with [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function. Note that if you put null pointer as the first argument, the function continues scanning the same string where a previous successful call to the function ended. So if you need next token just call

```
char* token = strtok(NULL, delimeters);
```

See small example below

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "The quick brown fox";

    // split str by space
    char* token = strtok(str, " ");

    // if a token is found
    if(token != NULL) {
        // print current token
        printf("%s\n", token);
        // if token is "The"
        if(strcmp(token, "The") == 0) {
            // print next token
            printf("%s\n", strtok(NULL, " "));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
The
quick
```